# Using a function in a KendoGrid template

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nLTniNMVxavYyv7Rpx6u?p=preview) I have an AngularJS KendoGrid with two columns: code and name. The code is a number, and the name is a function of the code: `getName(code)`. I put the function in a template, however I'm getting `function undefined`. Any ideas?

HTML

```
   <div kendo-grid="grid" 
        k-data-source="ds" 
        k-options="gridOptions"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", [ "kendo.directives" ]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {


    $scope.gridOptions = {
            columns: [
              {
                        field: "code"
                },
                {
                    field: "name",
                    template: '#= getName(code) #'
             }]
  };


    var getName = function(code) {
      return "This code is " + code;
    };


    $scope.ds = [{ code: 1  },
              { code: 2 },
              { code: 3 },
              { code: 4 },
              { code: 5 }];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For kendo templates, the #= something # syntax is for rendering values as HTML so you can't call a function like that.

Leave out the = sign and just use 
    # something #
to execute arbitrary javascript

see: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview

Comment: [please see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/D6R6B7D0PYGoCgy4zHQx?p=preview), still not working

Comment: Yes, executing functions in templates is tricky. It has to do with scope. If you put getName() in the global scope by removing var then it works. I wouldn't recommend doing that. I usually avoid functions in kendo templates. You could get the same effect by changing your template to: 'This code is #= code #'. Which is how they are meant to be used.

Comment: I need to use a javascript function in a grid column, either with a template or something else, is there a workaround? I cannot put the function in the global scope.

Comment: The workaround would be to write your function logic inside of the template, if it's not too complicated. If it is too complicated, then you need to preprocess your data before supplying it to the grid.

Comment: what about updating directly the related data source? can I trigger a function that updates field `a` when field `b` changes?

Answer (score 5):

You can use angular template expressions such as `{{ }}` as well as kendo expressions such as `#= #`. For your example try:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
   columns: [
      { field: "code" },
      {
        field: "name",
        template: '{{ getName(dataItem.code) }}'
      }
   ]
};
$scope.getName = function(code) {
  return "This code is " + code;
};
```

See this demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@pesho/iMASa/2

Comment: On the one hand, I am super happy as this solution worked perfectly for me.  On the other hand I'm super sad as this project I've inherited is still on AngularJS and there's no budget to upgrade to latest ;)